# Highlight sections of a CPTScatterPlot

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-plot, appkit

I would like to highlight certain sections of interest in my `CPTScatterPlot`.

Searching through the documentation and looking at the demo apps and the demo apps didn't provide any insights if this is a built-in feature.

Basically I'd like to turn a `CPTScatterPlot` like this

[image]

into something similar to this:

[image]

Should I overlay a second plot for just the sections of interest..?

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a second plot is the solution here.

Comment: Thanks, Eric - works like a breeze: https://imgur.com/8oiCO8a
Depending on the setup playing around with plot's (i.e. layer's) `zPosition` might be necessary to make the overlay plot visible.